# how to access Nextcloud (running on a local machine) from outside?

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I want to run a Nextcloud instance on our office's local server and use that to access files from outside. As I have little experience with networking setup I'd like to confirm the general architecture

Components involved are:

- ASUS RT-N66U Router
- Modem (provided by ISP [China Telecom])
- a dynamic public IP address
- ubuntu server (18.04, maybe 16.04)
- Nextcloud 12 (either from the snap package, or running a manual install in a LXD container)

I think what I have to do is:

- setup a DDNS service (no-ip is what plan to use)
- install Open-WRT on our router
- create a VPN connection to that router which the clients from outside will be using to connect
- enable https access on the Nextcloud server

does that sound about right?

Comment: That all looks about right to me.  When you are going to use the router as your connection make sure that your modem is only a modem or capable of using a Transparent connection so that it is passed through directly to your router.  Other than that, your list looks good.

Comment: thanks Terrance. The router is already managing our internal network, with the Modem (which could be a router too) only serving as a modem. So I guess perquisites are fulfilled on that part

Answer (score 0):

so, the first part works and was quite easy to achieve.

the ASUS router has a built-in DDNS service and pointing that to my no-ip.com account plus setting up port forwarding (`80:80`, `430:430`, `8080:8080` for the moment) did the job.

So for now I regard this matter as solved, thanks